passbolt can't send TLS mails to postal server
If you think this question is better suited for stack overflow or superuser, then tell me and I will close the question and repost.
I'm having a passbolt server running as docker container.
I'm also having a postal server for mail delivery https://docs.postalserver.io/
We had a working setup and something must have changed (another admin modified something by accident, somebody stopped / restarted the docker containers of passbolt or postal, I don't know)
The problem is.
I can send mails from passbolt to postal (listening on port 25) but only if I disable TLS.
If I use another software to send mails (like for example swaks http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/ )
I do see, that by connecting to port 25 of the postal server I can upgrade to TLS
the swaks traces:
=== Trying mail.mydomain.com:25...
=== Connected to mail.mydomain.com.
<-  220 mail.mydomain.com ESMTP Postal/GV6ICJ7B
 -> EHLO localhost
<-  250-My capabilities are
<-  250-STARTTLS
<-  250 AUTH CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
 -> STARTTLS
<-  220 Ready to start TLS
=== TLS started with cipher TLSv1.3:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:256
=== TLS no local certificate set
=== TLS peer DN="/CN=mail.mydomain.com"
 ~> EHLO localhost
<~  250-My capabilities are
<~  250 AUTH CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
 ~> AUTH LOGIN
...
<~  235 Granted for mydomain/notify
....

The passbolt error message:
"The test email could not be sent. Kindly check the logs below for more information."
followed by these traces:
[
    {
        "cmd": null,
        "response": [
            {
                "code": "220",
                "message": "mail.mydomain.fr ESMTP Postal/3JDHAWRI"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "cmd": "EHLO bolt.mydomain.fr",
        "response": [
            {
                "code": "250",
                "message": "My capabilities are"
            },
            {
                "code": "250",
                "message": "STARTTLS"
            },
            {
                "code": "250",
                "message": "AUTH CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "cmd": "STARTTLS",
        "response": [
            {
                "code": "220",
                "message": "Ready to start TLS"
            }
        ]
    }
]

Tp me the passbolt traces seem to indicate, that it never even tries to establish an TLS connection, but that it just aborts.
Could this be TLS version issuues? but nothing is displayed.
Is there any way to get more verbose error logs or to better understand what excactly fails?
Preferably I'd like to debug on the passbolt site as restarting and reconfiguring the postal server is more sensitive, but I'm open to any suggestion.
The configuration for email server is:
auth method: username & password
username: mydomain/notify
password: xxxxxx
smtp host: mail.mydomain.fr
port: 25
use_tls: yes (if set to 'no' then everything works, but swaks can use tls)

Where is your error message? Where is your passbolt config?

The error is "The test email could not be sent. Kindly check the logs below for more information." followed by the logs, that I posted.
The logs just stop after starttls. Normally traces should probably (like in the swaks traces) show a switch over to starttls and some authentication.
Perhaps tls incompatibilities, but I don't know how to get traces.

@symcbean  is the modified article better understandable?
